# While loop in BASH script causing syntax error

Tags: bash

I recently started writing BASH scripts, and I am currently trying to practice using while loops. However, when I run the following block of code, the command prompt responds with:

```
run.command: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
run.command: `done'
```

Then the program shuts off.
This is the code I am running.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "text"
c=false
while true; do
    printf ">> "
    i=read 
    if [$i = "exit"]; then
        exit
    else if [$i = "no"]; then
        echo "no"
    else
        echo -e "Error: $i is undefined"
    fi
done
```

I did some research on while loops, however my loop syntax seems correct. When I remove the done at the end, and `Unexpected end of file` error occurs. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-p` option of read for the prompt and a `case ... esac` construction:

```
while true; do
  read -r -p ">> " i
  case "$i" in
     "exit") exit 0  ;;
     "no") echo "no" ;;
     *) echo -e "Error: $i is undefined";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll do more research on this.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "text"
c=false
while true; do
  printf ">> "
  read i
  if [ "$i" = "exit" ]; then
    exit
  elif [ "$i" = "no" ]; then
     echo "no"
  else
     echo -e "Error: $i is undefined"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You should quote `$i`, to avoid a "too many arguments" error from `[`.

Comment: Explanation: Test it with `an input with two or more words`. You can use `"$i"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there any more things I can improve upon?

Comment: @Jerrybibo, using `echo -e` is actually best avoided: Supporting that option to do anything other than print `-e` on output is contrary to the POSIX spec for `echo`. If you want format string support, use `printf`.

Comment: @Jerrybibo, ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for the aforementioned specification (and note all the caveats: Behavior when given a string with *any* backslash is undefined in POSIX echo; behavior when given `-n` is undefined; behavior when given `-e` *is* defined, but defined in such a way as to require `-e` to be printed on output; etc).

Comment: @Jerrybibo, ...personally, I'd write your first prompt like so: `printf '%s\n' "" "" "JxOS" "Version dev_a1.0"`